# Change structure of XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I need to take this text file [http://gis.fcd.maricopa.gov/apps/forecastzone/wxlabels.txt](http://alert.fcd.maricopa.gov/alert/Google/v3/php/msp.php) and using php export an xml file.  I have this current code which exports the xml but I need a different format

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("MST"); //or whatever your default timezone is.
header("Content-Type: text/xml"); 

$fp = fopen('http://gis.fcd.maricopa.gov/apps/forecastzone/wxlabels.txt', 'r');

$xml = new XMLWriter;
$xml->openURI('php://output');
$xml->startDocument(); 
$xml->setIndent(true); // makes output cleaner

$xml->startElement('messages'); 

while ($line = fgetcsv($fp)) {

   $xml->startElement('zones');
   $xml->writeElement('name', $line[0]);
   $xml->writeElement('times', $line[1]);
   $xml->endElement();
}

$xml->endElement();

?>
```

It exports to http://alert.fcd.maricopa.gov/alert/Google/v3/php/msp.php and looks like this:

```
<messages>
<zones>
<name>Gila Bend</name>
<times>2:00pm-5:00pm</times>
</zones>
</messages>
```

I need it to look like this:

```
<messages>
<zones name="Gila Bend" times="2:00pm-5:00pm"</zones>
</messages>
```

What do I need to add/edit in my php file?

Comment: Have a look here http://php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-write-attribute.php

Comment: I have but keep getting errors in the output when I try to add startAttribute @rjdown

Comment: You're going to need to give more information than that. Show what you tried, and what the errors were.

Comment: Here is the error I am getting http://alert.fcd.maricopa.gov/alert/Google/v3/php/msp2.php             $xml->startElement('messages'); 
while ($line = fgetcsv($fp)) {
$xml->startElement('zones');
$xml->startAttribute('name');
$xml->text($line[0]);
$xml->endAttribute();
$xml->endElement();
}

$xml->endElement();
@rjdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("MST"); //or whatever your default timezone is.
header("Content-Type: text/xml"); 

$fp = fopen('http://gis.fcd.maricopa.gov/apps/forecastzone/wxlabels.txt', 'r');

$xml = new XMLWriter;
$xml->openURI('php://output');
$xml->startDocument(); 
$xml->setIndent(true); // makes output cleaner

$xml->startElement('messages'); 

while ($line = fgetcsv($fp)) {

   $xml->startElement('zones');
   $xml->writeAttribute('name', $line[0]);
   $xml->writeAttribute('times', $line[1]);
   $xml->endElement();
}

$xml->endElement();

?>
```